# JNA C structure to Java

Tags: c#, pointers, memory, jna

I have a C# code that I have to re-write in Java. 
Methods are in dll.

results

```
OK = 0,
ERR_GENERAL = 1,           
ERR_INVALID_HANDLE = 5,         
ERR_OUT_OF_MEMORY = 11,
ERR_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED = 12,
ERR_OPERATION_NOT_SUPPORTED = 13,
ERR_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL = 14
```

C# code

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public struct jobInfo
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 64)]
            public string Atr;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 64)]
            public string JobName;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
            public bool IsSupported;
            public int Status;


        }

public static extern int search(string atr, out int job);
public static extern int getInfo(int job, ref JobInfo jobInfo);

int result=0;
int job=0;
result = search(null, out job); // result=0
JobInfo info=new JobInfo();
result=getInfo(job,ref info); // result=0
//info.Atr=354BBG
//info.JobName=Java developer
//info.IsSupported=true
//info.Status=active
```

Job info

```
 public class JobInfo extends Structure {
        public String Atr;
        public String JobName;
        public boolean IsSupported;
        public long Status;


        public JobInfo() {

        }

        public JobInfo(Pointer pointer) {
            super(pointer);
        }

        public static class ByReference extends JobInfo implements Structure.ByReference {
            public ByReference() {
            }

            public ByReference(Pointer p) {
                super(p);
                read();
            }

        }

        public static class ByValue extends JobInfo implements Structure.ByValue {
            public ByValue() {
            }

            public ByValue(Pointer p) {
                super(p);
                read();
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
            return Arrays.asList(new String[] { "Atr", "JobName", "IsSupported", "Status" });
        }
```

Java code

```
    public int search(String atr, IntByReference card);

    public int getInfo(long card, ByReference jobInfo);

    int result=0;
    IntByReference job = new IntByReference(0);
    result = Native.search(null, job); // result=0
    JobInfo.ByReference info = new JobInfo.ByReference();
    result = Native.getInfo(job, info); // result=5
```

I have tried with `info.getPointer()`, I tried to pass `new PointerByReference` to `getJob()` but result is always 5 (ERR_INVALID_HANDLE).

C code

```
typedef void* Job;
typedef unsigned long int  JOBLong;   

struct JobInfo
    {
        char        Atr[64];            
        char        JobName[64];       
        bool        IsSupported;        
        JOBLong     Status;            
    };


   FUNCTION(search) 
    (
        char      atr[64],    
        Job*      Job   
    );

    FUNCTION(getInfo)
    (
        Job     job,      
        JobInfo* jobInfo    
    );
```

I have another methods but I will ask another question about them if I manage to solve this.

**Edit:**

If I do it like this

```
Pointer job;
PointerByReference handle = new PointerByReference();
result = Native.search(null, handle);               
job = handle.getValue();
JobInfo info = new JobInfo();
result = Native.getInfo(job, info.getPointer()); // result=0
```

Result is 0 but info fields are null

Comment: How come you are using `long` in the Java method declaration, but `int` in C#? Sizes matter.

Comment: Bacause if I use int I got 12 (ERR_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED)

Comment: You should match the C code, not the C# code.   Make your `Atr` and `JobName` variables `byte[]` arrays initialized to the right length.  You don't tell us where you've defined `JobLong`.   Declaring the `ByReference` mapping for `JobInfo` is unnecessary, a structure passed to a function is automatically considered as a pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed String field into byte array and now it works

```
 public class JobInfo extends Structure {
     public byte[] Atr=new byte[64];
     public byte[] JobName=new byte[64];
     public int IsSupported;
     public int Status;    

    public JobInfo() {}

 @Override
 protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
    return Arrays.asList(new String[] { "Atr", "JobName", "IsSupported", "Status" });
        }
  }
```